# how to use method on specific object from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

EDIT2: Sorry all... I believe it is due to the lack of understanding of question that cause this misconception. After reading through, I think what they want is for the return value of getWinningPoint() be the biggest number among the players and yet still <=21. so that in the game output, can loop each player to get their card point again and compare it to this winningpoint. I thank all of your input and help. Moderator or Admin can close this thread. Thanks again.

I would like to find out how to access the particular object in the arraylist so that i can cast the method on it. In a overall view, I am able to make method that apply to all items in the arraylist of players (distributeCardsToPlayer). But my 2nd method of `getWinningPoints()` is a int that sum up all the cards the particular player in arraylist players have. The winningPoint is a individual result which will ultimately be used in `printWinners()` method. I'm only familiar with accessing a obj with "`Player player = players.get(0);`" but in this case the "player" itself will be calling `getWinningPoints()` to check their own result.

P.S - I am not sure how to put it properly,and hopefully someone can point me to the right direction.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ModifiedBlackJack
{
protected ArrayList<Card> gameDeck;
protected ArrayList<Player> players;

public ModifiedBlackJack(ArrayList<Player> players)
{
    this.players=players;
}

public void distributeCardsToPlayers()
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (Player player : players)
    {
        player.drawACard(getACardFromDeck());
        player.drawACard(getACardFromDeck());
        System.out.println(player.getName()+": " + player.toString()); 
        System.out.print("Draw another card? (y/n): ");
        char input = console.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        if(input == 'y')
        {
            player.drawACard(getACardFromDeck());
        }
    }
```

EDIT2: After reading through, I think what they want is for the return value of getWinningPoint() be the biggest number among the players and yet still <=21. so that in the game output, can loop each player to get their card point again and compare it to this winningpoint.

```
public int getWinningPoints()
{
    int wp=0;;
    int point=0;
    for (Player player:players)
    {
        point = player.getCardsPoints();
        if (point>=21 && point>wp)
        {
            wp=point;
        }
    }
    return wp;
}
```

In the Player class, there is a function for summing up all the cards point

```
public int getCardsPoints()
{
    int point=0;
    for (Card c: cards)
    {
        point=point+c.getPoints();
    }
    return point;
}
```

I am new to java and any help or guidance is very much appreciated. 
Thank You

Comment: To clarify:  your goal is to print out the points for all players at the end of the game, correct?

Comment: in printWinners(int min) it will print out the summed point. but to get the summed point is through the getWinningPoint() method. but i am unsure how to build the getWinningPoint() method because I don't have a clear object to reference the method from my Player class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be overthinking this, and the method `getWinningPoints` isn't entirely required.

Because you *already* have `getCardsPoints` declared in `Player`, and you already have an instance of `Player` to work with in your loop, the only thing you realistically need to do is...invoke it.

```
System.out.println(player.getName() + "Chips: " + player.getChips() + "[]" + player.getCardsPoints());
```

Whatever conditions you need to satisfy the `min` parameter should be done inside of this loop; that is, conditionally print the values that are larger than `min`.

Comment: unfortunately the method getWinningPoints() is part of the requirement... but yes, I agree entirely with you. That is what I would have work towards/done if there is no requirement for the getWinningPoints() method.

Comment: thank you, it seems i really over think. getWinningPoint() should only get me a int value to compare with player.getCardsPoints() in my loop. And if they are equal, my noOfWinner will ++.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke a Player class method you need to have a player object to call a method that it "owns".

Pass the player object to the method and accept the player object in getWinningPoints().

**Call**

```
getWinningPoints(player)
```

**Declaration**

```
public int getWinningPoints(Player localPlayer)
{
   return localPlayer.getCardsPoints();
}
```

Comment: base on the requirements, theres no input for the method. so i assume in the main app output will go something similar to "int result =  player.getWinningPoints()" so im trying to figure out if it is possible for the method to self access base on who call it.

Comment: You have access to the players arraylist. So you could loop through the players arraylist in getWinningPoints() so you don't have to pass anything to it..

Comment: the looping of player through the arraylist will be done else where. so when the method is called, it will be the particular player calling. but how will the method know which player is using it? like in distribute method, there is a loop, so all player will get the cards. but in winningPoint, only 1 player will be calling it at a time.